# SQL: Copying entire tables without an identification column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically my question is how would I copy a certain table without (as in the entirety of its contents) the identity column?

To elaborate, lets say I have a schema called `completed_tasks` and I would like to insert all of its contents in `completed_tasks_archive`:

```
$stmt = $GLOBALS['conn']->prepare("INSERT INTO completed_tasks_archive SELECT * FROM completed_tasks; ");
$stmt->execute();
```

The code ought to work normally but due to the identity column, which I would refer to as `ID` I cannot perform this operation.

I get an error like this one:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]An explicit value for the identity column in table 'completed_tasks_archive' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
```

Basically, I am wondering to whether or not is there a quicker way to do this transaction of data without specifying all the nitty-gritty details in the query.

I am using MS SQLSRV to store the data.

> And I kind of begin to hate MS SQLSRV after working with MySQLi for a couple of weeks.

I apologise if my question is a bit convoluted but I am still learning on how to use all of this and, more importantly, learn how to use it elegantly.

Comment: The target table has the identity as well.  If you're doing this for historical reasons then it doesn't make sense to have this identity property.  You could just alter that column (in SSMS is fine) to remove the identity property from the target table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using a column with autoincrement identity, you have to enable inserting for this column.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT completed_tasks_archive ON;
```

After performing your insert you should deactivate it.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT completed_tasks_archive OFF;
```

You also have to provide the column names. A "*" is not sufficient.

Have a look at [IDENTITY INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)